# Drive permission in windows 7 ultimate

Tags: windows-7

I want to show drives (i.e. d, e, f) only to administrators is that possible in windows 7 ultimate?

Answer (score 0):

Use gpedit.msc

Go to Local Computer Policy >User Configuration >Administrative templates >Windows Components >Windows Explorer

In the right pane configure "Hide These Specified drives in My Computer"

for more restrictions see "Prevent Access to drives in My Computer"

its not very selective on what drives you can restrict.

This may be a better way
http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=5882

Comment: I used your way but now I can't see any hard drive